# Line integral in terms of one variable

Tags: integration

I'm integrating a function of electric field to find voltage and I've got to a point and got stuck. I know that the integral form is $ V =\int_A^B E \cdot dL $ and my function of $ E$ is $ y \hat x + x \hat y$, the path is $ x=(1+y)^2 $ and the coordinates are $ A = (4,1,-2)$ and $B=(9,2,-2) $. I've gotten to $ V = - \int_A^B y dx + (1+y)^2 dy$ but I'm not sure how to get dy or dx in terms of one or the other and then where do I go from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to parametrize the path along which you integrate. This is done by

$$\gamma(y)=((1+y)^2,y,-2).$$

Then you calculate the velocity vector, by differentiating the above parametrization, and get

$$\dot{\gamma}(y)=(2+2y)\hat{x}+\hat{y}.$$

Now you want to calculate the scalar product $E\cdot\dot{\gamma}$ at every point as a function of $y$:

$$E(\gamma(y))\cdot\dot{\gamma}(y)=(y\hat{x}+x\hat{y})\cdot((2+2y)\hat{x}+\hat{y})=y(2+2y)+x=y(2+2y)+(1+y)^2.$$

All you have left to do now is integrate:

$$\int_\gamma E\cdot d\gamma=\int_1^2(y(2+2y)+(1+y)^2)dy$$

Comment: Cheers, I knew I had to do something like that but I wasn't quite sure.